# Config Environment values

Tags: keycloak

I've created a event listener spi for key cloak using which I log events to azure queue.
Key cloak is deployed on different environment with their separate queues for logging.
I need to pass different connection string for each environment.
Is there a way to pass different queue connection string when running on different environments. Can I use **--config-file** to pass config values to key cloak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keycloak has built-in support for configuring providers. Check out the ["Configuring providers"](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration-provider) guide.

You need to implement the `init(Config.Scope config)` method from the `EventListenerProviderFactory` to read the config properties via `config.get("property name", "default value")`.